# Array returned using method reading Column names from MySQL database is full of "null"

Tags: java, mysql, database, arrays, null

I am writing a webservice using Java to communicate with a database that I have set up on a MySQL server running on my localhost machine. My method,ListColumns(), to look up the names of the columns in a specified table and convert them from a ResultSet to an array then return that array; is returning an array of the correct size but that is full "null" values.

```
    import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {

private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;

public DBConnect(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/binapartslist";
        String userID = "root";
        String userPW = "root";     
        //jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/`database name` --> This is the database
        //userID database user
        //userPW user password

        //Connecting to the database
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, userID, userPW);
        st = con.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }
}
public String getUser(){
    try{
        DatabaseMetaData dmd = con.getMetaData();
        String username = dmd.getUserName();
        //System.out.println("Current User: "+username);
        return username;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
public void getData(String table){
    int i=1;
    try{

        String query = "select * from "+table;
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Records from Database");

        String[] columnNames = ListColumns(table);
        int count = columnNames.length;
        System.out.println(ListColumns(table));

        System.out.println("number of columns "+count);         
        for(i=0; i<count; i++){
            System.out.println(columnNames[i]);
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
public int countTables (String database){
    try{
        DatabaseMetaData dmd = con.getMetaData();
        rs= dmd.getTables(null, database, "%", null);

        int count=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            count++;
        }
        return count;

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);         
        return 0;
    }

}   
public int countColumns (String table){
    try{
        DatabaseMetaData dmd = con.getMetaData();
        rs = dmd.getColumns(null, null, table, "%");

        int count=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            count++;
        }
        return count;

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);         
        return 0;
    }

}
public String[] ListColumns(String table){
    String[] columnsList = new String[countColumns(table)];
    try{            
        DatabaseMetaData dmd = con.getMetaData();
        rs = dmd.getColumns(null, null, table, "%");

        int i=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            columnsList[i]=rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("columnsList[] has "+columnsList.length+" values");
        for(i=0;i<columnsList.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Column Name: "+columnsList[i]);
        }
        return columnsList;         
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("i screwed up");
        System.out.println(ex);         
        return columnsList;
    }
}
public String[] ListTables(String database){
    try{
        DatabaseMetaData dmd = con.getMetaData();
        rs = dmd.getTables(null, database, "%", null);

        System.out.println(database);
        String[] tablesList = new String[countTables(database)];
        int i=0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            tablesList[i]=rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            System.out.println("table name: "+rs.getString(3));
            i++;
        }               
        return tablesList;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
public void createUser(String username, String password, String rank) throws SQLException{
    try{
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('"+username+"', '"+password+"', '"+rank+"');");
        con.commit();
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }catch (Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                    con.rollback();
                }catch(Exception excep) {
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.rollback();
                        con.setAutoCommit(true);
                      }
                    System.out.println(excep);
                }
            }
    }
}
public void deleteUser(String username) throws SQLException{
    try{
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE username = '"+username+"'");
        con.commit();
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }catch (Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                    con.rollback();
                }catch(Exception excep) {
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.rollback();
                        con.setAutoCommit(true);
                      }
                    System.out.println(excep);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

I am calling the class that those methods are in with the following code:

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
            DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
            System.out.println(connect.getUser());
            System.out.println(connect.ListColumns("parts list"));
            connect.ListColumns("parts list");
        }


    }
```

I need columnsList() to return the array with the Strings of the column names.
EDIT: I have already confirmed that the array columnsList[] is actually receiving the column names using the for loop and println. Just can not figure out why the return is still full of nulls

Also added all of the code I am using. The ListTables() method is very similar and having the same issues but I figure if I get one fixed the other will be fixed also

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came into work after the weekend and the code just decided to work finally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious bug. I would debug the code and inspect the result set in the while(rs.next()) loop.

The following tutorial has a code sample for "Listing Tables".

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/databasemetadata.html

There are two differences to your code:

- the result set column is accessed by index
- the columnPattern is passed as null.

Probably "COLUMN_NAME" is not the column used by mysql for the column name.

```
public static String[] listColumns(){
    String[] columnsList = new String[2];
    try{    

        columnsList[0] = "0";

        if (true) throw new RuntimeException();

        columnsList[1] = "1";

        return columnsList;         
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //a println to check if the catch is filling up the array with null
        System.out.println("i screwed up");
        System.out.println(ex);         
        return columnsList;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(listColumns()));
}
```

This code prints:

```
  i screwed up 
  java.lang.RuntimeException 
  [0, null]
```

Comment: I have already checked the while(rs.next()) loop and the array columnsList[] gets filled up with the correct information before it leaves the method, but the array that is actually returned is just full of null's

Comment: How did you check this? (Probably not with the println in the main method, because this will only print the array object id.) Did the for loop with the println print the column names?

Comment: I did check it with the for loop using the println to print the contents of that array, and all of the columns printed correctly, but the returned array was still of full null

Comment: I think the array of nulls results from the exception handling

Comment: in the catch(Exception ex)? The println that says screwed up doesnt ever get printed

Comment: Did you change something on the main method too? Sorry, beside this, I don't have any further ideas.